# Normal Subgroups, index, divisible orders

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ with index $k$ . Show that if $a \in G$  and $o(a)=n$, then the order of $aH$ in $G/H$ divides both $n$ and $k$ .

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: I am so lost in this class i dont even know what to try the only thing even similar this this question my teacher has talked about is a groups whose order is prime and he didnt even finish that proof

Comment: Ok, first thing to do is write down what the definition of the order of an element is. Then write down how the multiplication in $G/H$ is defined. Then see what kinds of results you have been taught that say something about something dividing other things in connection to groups.

Comment: okay i will start that thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In any group, $x^m = 1$ if and only if the order of $x$ divides $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are

> $(aH)^{o(aH)}=H$

some hints

> $a^{o(aH)}H=H$

if you

> $a^{o(aH)}\in H$

get stuck

> Now give it a good old fashioned Lagrangin'

:)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** In $G/H$ you have $(aH)^n = a^nH$.